# A loop to check rows for 1/0's and stores in a new dataset (jupyter pandas python)

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,1,0,0,0],
                           'b':[0,0,1,0,0,0],
                           'c':[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           'd':[0,0,0,0,1,1]})
print (dataframe1)

   a  b  c  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  0  1
```

I then define a new dataset lets say:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'Total':[0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

How would I create a method of checking each row in the original dataframe, seeing if there is at least one `1`, if so placing an `1` in the new dataset on the same row. If there no `1`'s in the original dataset, it would set the equivalent row in `Total` as 0.

In our case only row number `3` has all `0`'s. The rest of the row's have `1`'s so would return:

```
   Total 
0  0  
1  1  
2  1  
3  0  
4  1  
5  1
```

Note my dataset has 8,000 rows, meaning it would have to check all rows, without listing them one by one.
How do I write that in code?

Comment: `df["Total"] = dataframe1.any(axis=1).astype(int)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> (dataframe1.any(1) + 0).to_frame('Total')

   Total
0      0
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      1
5      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using `np.where` method:

```
df['Total'] = np.where(df.any(1), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
print(df['Total'])

    Total
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   1
```